# Not able to initiate call in X-socket for Webrtc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webrtc

I am trying to work on webrtc from x-socket.
Below is the link where i found the demo.

http://xsockets.net/api/webrtc-api

I had done the coding in the same exact way.
But in the demo i am able to make and initiate the call.
But the demo which i created by using all this function not permit me to initiate the call.

The method which i used to initiate call is :-
 XSockets.WebRTC.CallManager.call (peerContext)
 http://xsockets.net/api/webrtc-api#snippet161

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Install the nuget package for the XSockets webrtc demo and you will get a working example.

PM> Install-Package XSockets.Sample.WebRTC